# Android Multiple project with Same Codebase

Tags: android

I  have  multiple android app running on same code base but the  project resource and API are different. I have read the following question  [How to create multiple Android apps from one code base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188250/how-to-create-multiple-android-apps-from-one-code-base) and my problem is that how to manage the project resource like images,color,text which was entirely different in each app.

Answer (score 0):

Resources in app projects override ones with the same name in library projects. So you just add the images, etc. to your app project and it works out more or less automatically.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay . The pkg name are different then how it should work

Comment: It doesn't matter, resources are managed at the app project level, so they will end up inside the right package.