# Building 2 applications from same codebase

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to build to different applications from the same codebase. The first application has a feature to provide carpool's, and the second application has features to search and register to carpools. Now both these applications need to be different. Their entry point is all I need to be different. Is there a way to provide a build time option to change the Intent-Filter during launch ?

There are many suggestions for creating jar's for common functionality. But I dont want to do it like that. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Hope this help to u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188250/how-to-create-multiple-android-apps-from-one-code-base & http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/index.html

Comment: I have been through both, no they dont address my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This requires factoring your code in such a way that it can be configurable at build time. This often times would require programatic files (manifest, java files, build files, etc...) editing of certain files to work with build time.

Comment: Ant is a solid choice for building, but you need programatic file editing like python/ruby.

Comment: I thought I could avoid it, and there is a simpler solution somewhere. I'll wait a while before accepting the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Refactoring also requires that you introduce new kinds of Design patterns as well such as inheritance with Singletons and configuring this at build time, still requires changing files. I dont think you can escape this. But keep searching.

Comment: Yeah, That is what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 
Create two manifest files.
Compile using Maven (I assume you could use Ant too for this)
Create two profiles.
Set the manifest depending on the profile.

ie.

pom.xml

```
 <profile>
     <id>Target1</id>
     <properties>
        <customerManifest>Target1Manifest.xml</customerManifest>
      </properties>
      </profile>
 <profile>
     <id>Target2</id>
     <properties>
        <customerManifest>Target2Manifest.xml</customerManifest>
      </properties>
      </profile>

<plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <androidManifestFile>${customerManifest}</androidManifestFile>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>15</platform>
                    </sdk>

            </plugin>
```

This switches out the manifest so you can set your seperate entry points.

Comment: so when you build call mvn clean package -P TargetX